# how to serve data from multiple urls (languages) from wikipedia API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, wikipedia-api

Some data I need is only available in the es (spanish version) of wikipedia and this is breaking my script I am using this tidbit to call the data as you can see it calls from  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php but this particular data is only available from https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

However I still need the english data as well

So how can i convert this to fetch from both api urls my knowledge of JS is minimal so please bear that in mind when replying thanks

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',

    data: {
        format: 'json',
        action: 'parse',
        page: this_target,
        prop:'text',
        section:0,
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
    //console.log(data)
    $(id_target).find('.o-modal__inner').html('');
    $(id_target).find('.o-modal__title').html('').hide();    
    $(id_target).find('.o-modal').addClass('isOpen');
    if(!$(id_target).find('.a-more').hasClass('isActive')){
        $(id_target).find('.a-more').trigger('click');
     }
    var markup = data.parse.text['*'];
    var i = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
    i.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });
    i.find('sup').remove();
    i.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
     setTimeout(function() {
        $(id_target).find('.o-modal__title').html( data.parse.title).fadeIn(300);
        $(id_target).find('.o-modal__inner').html($(i).find('p'));
        $(id_target).find('.a-loader').hide();
      }, 1000);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for `data.error` in top of `success` callback and if so for english page, resend ajax request just by replacing the subdomain:

```
if (data.error && new URL(this.url).hostname === "en.wikipedia.org") {
    this.url = this.url.replace('en', 'es')
    $.ajax(this);
    return;
  } else if(data.error) {
    console.log('No data to display from both english & spanish wiki');
    return;
  }
```

Comment: speaking french to me :) am i to insert your code between these lines  sorry i really know very little about JS I just tracked it down to this tidbit.... dataType: 'jsonp', if (data.error && new URL(this.url).hostname === "en.wikipedia.org") {
    this.url = this.url.replace('en', 'es')
    $.ajax(this);
    return;
  }                                                                                                                         
    success: function (data) {

Comment: No, you have to set inside of success callback, at top of it: `success: function(data) { if (data.error && new URL(this.url).hostname === "en.wikipedia.org") {...} ...},`. BTW, i updated answer to handle case there is nothing to display for both wikis